# Dot character in file name for HTTPClient Console Application gives 400 Bad Request Error

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dotnet-httpclient

I have a console application that uploads file in a web server using `HTTPClient`. Relevant Code  -

```
var client = new HttpClient();

//Set Auth Headers

var response = client.PutAsync(fullUrl, content).Result;
```

This works fine until I have a dot in the `fullUrl`. I read about using `relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping` in `web.config`. I added it in my `App.config` file since this is a console application but it is having no effect. What are the other options to make it work?

Working Sample URL - http://myServer/commons/1.0/commons-logging-1-0.jar

Non Working Sample URL - http://myServer/commons/1.0/commons-logging-1.0.jar

Notice the non working JAR name has the name `commons-logging-1.0.jar` in place of `commons-logging-1-0.jar`

The exception I get is `StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request'`

Comment: post the sample (but valid) fullUrl

Comment: How does a valid (working) url looks like?

Comment: This is more likely a server problem than a client problem.  Do you control the server?

Comment: I do not control the server. But I can post the same file manually in the same server so this should not be a server problem

Comment: It really appeared to be a server side problem. The same code could upload the file in a different server. I was able to find this out through FIDDLER which clearly stated the error. Thanks Darrel.

Answer (score 0):

The period is a valid URL character. The problem that you have is not related to period. If you dynamically building your URL you should escape your query string. Escaped period is equivalent to '%2E', so try that and if you still getting the same error then you should try to trace your request/response using Chrome debugger tool (F12) or Fiddler tool and check what is sent to the server.

There are number of ways to encode URL string in C#, one of them is HttpUtility

```
string url = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("http://myServer/commons/1.0/commons-logging-1.0.jar");
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working too. Giving url after URL encode gives `An invalid request URI was provided. The request URI must either be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set.` exception. Using %2E in place of dot is not working either.